# customized chat window in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

Can we have customized chat window in a visual force page.

i.e can i have a custom chat window on visual force page where I can have custom chat form to receive and send sms .

Comment: Are you using Live Agent?

Comment: no, my requirement is will receive sms from the customer and would be saved in an object so these message should show up in vf page automatically The functionality should be of custom chat window

Comment: Ok, I will delete my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using the Twilio API. You'll need to have a visual force page on a a SF sites to set it up with. Here's link to a relevant StackOverflow post  [Unable to receive the sms via twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339900/unable-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio) on troubleshooting setting it up. There's also a blog on Twilio integration by [Abhi Tripathi](http://abhithetechknight.blogspot.in/2014/06/salesforce-integration-with-twilio.html) that you might find helpful to you as well. He explains step by step how he set up an account with Twilio and got the outbound portion working.

I wanted to add that you might want to research the Google API to see if they support hooking into their SMS API. Since SF supports a great amount of integration with Google Apps, particularly when it comes to supporting Gmail, it might be possible for users who have Gmail Accts even though I've never heard of anyone doing it. You might also want to look on the App Exchange to make certain you're not reinventing the wheel. ;)

If none of the above works out for you, there's also a paid app called [SMS Magic Interact](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000024XvyEAE) that would seem to be worth looking into. I can't say whether or not it would allow you to save the contents of messages to records "out of the box". The listing mentions all SMS History being logged as a related list to the record. It does seem to have an API that you could work with for customizations and also works with custom objects.

Comment: Thanks for informations.By using Twilio when a customer replies it creates a task  and adds to activity history.
In my requirement I want a custom chat window in contact object where I can receive the incoming messages and  also reply to the customer from the same chat window in my contact object

Answer (score 1):

As @crmprogdev mentioned If you are doing with Twilio You can look into 
 a Library  in  [Git Hub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce)  and video Explained by @metadaddy  [Twilio and Salesforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le3y29--79U)

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info. CloudSpokes also did an integration contest using Twilio some time ago as well. I no longer have the details at hand for the contest but your post reminded me there was a repository on [Github](https://github.com/cloudspokes/twilio-sms-forcedotcom) for getting started with it too.